# Положительные элементы массива заменить нулями

Tags: массивы, delphi, pascal

имеется массив заполняющийся рандомными числами. Hадо сделать так, чтобы все **положительные** элементы главной диагонали заменялись нулями. И выполнить это в виде функции.
Пока сделал такую программу, дальше что-то ступор пошел.

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

const
s=100;
var
mass:array [1..s,1..s] of integer;
i,j,n,m:integer;
begin
writeln('Vvedite kol-vo strok i stolbcov: ');
readln (n,m);
randomize;
for i:=1 to n do
    for j:=1 to m do
    begin
         if (i=j) then mass[i,j]:=0
         else
        mass[i,j]:=random(100)-25;
    end;

for i:=0 to n do
begin
    for j:=0 to m do
    if (i=0) then
    begin
    write('| ',j,' |');
    end
    else if (j=0) then
    begin
    write('| ',i,' |');
    end
    else if (i<>0) and (j<>0) then
         if (i=j) then
         write('| ',mass[i,j],' |')
         else
        write('|',mass[i,j],'|');
writeln;
end;
readln;
end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зачем что-то заменять, если у Вас и так:

```
if (i=j) then mass[i,j]:=0
```

---

```
uses Math;

...
for i := 1 to Min(n, m) do
begin
  if mass[i, i] > 0 then
    mass[i, i] := 0;
end;
```

Comment: начинать с 0 (а не с 1)

Comment: @VladChapl Это Вы мне? Нет, начинать с 1, а не с 0.

Comment: Да, точно. В условии про [0,0] ничего не сказано, а в коде принудительно стоит 0. Но, вполне вероятно, это сделано случайно. Так что что бы (как сказано в условии) "все положительные элементы главной диагонали заменялись нулями", поэтому начинать с 0.

Comment: @VladChapl кхм, кхм... Я не смог уловить основную мысль в Вашем тексте. Массив определен как индексированный с индекса `1` - `mass:array [1..s,1..s] of integer;`, поэтому начинать надо с единицы.

Comment: так в диагонали могут быть не только положительные элементы, я не знаю, как сделать,чтобы из диагонали все положительные заменились нулями.

Comment: @Vitaliy Какой смысл Вы вкладываете в слово "положительные"? Вам виден код в ответе?

Comment: что-то он не работает, ну в диагонали могут быть отрицательные и положительные элементы надо чтобы все положительные были нулями в окончательной матрице.

Comment: @Vitaliy Он работает. Вы просто неаккуратно его к себе скопировали.

Comment: вставляю пишет просто один 0 вместо массива.

Comment: @Vitaliy В моем коде нет ничего, что "пишет". Пишет Ваш код. Он неправильный.