# Создать функцию обработки массива

Tags: delphi, pascal

Помогите Создать функцию

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,math;

const
s=100;
var
mass:array [1..s,1..s] of integer;
i,j,n,m:integer;
begin
writeln('Vvedite kol-vo strok i stolbcov: ');
readln (n,m);
writeln('IshodnbIy massiv');
for i:=1 to n do
 begin
  for j:=1 to m do
   begin
    mass[i,j]:=25-random(50);
    write(mass[i,j]:5);
   end;
  writeln;
 end;
writeln('IzmenennbIy massiv');
for i:=1 to n do
begin
  for j:=1 to m do
  begin
      if mass[i,i]>0 then
      mass[i,i]:=0;
      write(mass[i,j]:5);
      end;
  writeln;
end;
readln;
end.
```

вот с этой частью кода

```
for i:=1 to n do
    begin
      for j:=1 to m do
      begin
          if mass[i,i]>0 then
          mass[i,i]:=0;
 end; 
end;
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Положительные элементы массива заменить нулями](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/922134/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const
  s = 100;
type
  TMass: array [1..s, 1..s] of integer;

procedure ChangeMainDiagonal(var aMass: TMass; n, m: integer);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to Min(m, n) do
  begin
    if aMass[i, i] > 0 then
      aMass[i, i] := 0;
  end; 
end;

var
  mass: TMass;
  i, j, n, m: integer;
begin
  ...
  ChangeMainDiagonal(mass, n, m);
  ...
```